# Как создать аплоадер для скачивания файлов с поиском?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Уже 3 день мучаюсь.Пытался вникнуть в суть вопроса, но даже не знаю куда копать.
Логика такая:
на веб хост будут заливаться файлы в текстовом формате по FTP в определенную папку.Это будет делать человек вручную.
В интерфейсе странички должен быть поиск.Если файл есть, ниже поля поиска его покажет.
При нажатии на него, его можно скачать.

Comment: Работка для фриланса :)

Comment: Покажите пример на что это должно быть похоже

Comment: Что то типа как на скриншоте:
http://piccy.info/view3/12483179/89e89f159ae43c16ab5d4085e4fb5b95/

Comment: Правильно подметил @Let'ssayPie, мы тут за вас всю работу писать не будем. Мы готовы помочь только в каких-то конкретных местах, но не во всей работе. Скажите конкретно в каком месте у вас проблемы возникают? Не знаете как список файлов вывести? Или как с формами работать?

Comment: Дело в том что форму я написал, она выше в скринах.
Я не понимаю какой под нее обработчик написать, чтоб он тянул информацию с папки в виде файла.
Думал что проще всего сделать scandir этой самой папки, а потом искать уже в полученном массиве.
Но перепробовал массу вариантов и пока без успехов

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы браузер не открывал документ, а скачивал его, надо добавить атрибут `download` к ссылке. Вот два примера
`<a href="test.txt">test</a>` тут браузер откроет файл

`<a href="test.txt" download>test</a>` а тут браузер скачает файл.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то:

```
$files = file("путь к папке");
$gfiles = array_keys($files, "Значение из поиска");


foreach($gfiles as $i => $v){

echo $v[$i] . '\n';

}
```

P.S. не уверен что правильно.